# Create an outer list from lists - python

Tags: python, list

I have following lists from user input

```
name = [ "name0", "name1", "name2" ]
year = [ "year0", "year1", "year2" ]
salary = [ "salary0", "salary1", "salary2"]
```

How do create a single outer list like this:

```
my_list = [["name0", "year0", "salary0"]
           ["name1", "year1", "salary1"]
           ["name2", "year2", "salary2"]]
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
for a in range(len(name)):
   my_list = [name[a], year[a], salary[a]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate all three lists together:

```
out = [list(data) for data in zip(name, year, salary)]
```

For your current code to work, you could define an empty list first, then append a sublist in loop:

```
my_list = []
for a in range(len(name)):
    my_list.append([name[a], year[a], salary[a]])
```

Output:

```
[['name0', 'year0', 'salary0'],
 ['name1', 'year1', 'salary1'],
 ['name2', 'year2', 'salary2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using numpy array, you can just transpose the three lists and you will get you desired output.

```
np.array([name,year,salary]).T
Out[31]: 
array([['name0', 'year0', 'salary0'],
       ['name1', 'year1', 'salary1'],
       ['name2', 'year2', 'salary2']], dtype='<U7')
```